# Formatting a value in column in RadGrid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

Please help me, how I can find the highest number in each column and format it to make it Bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this approch.

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] numericColumns = { "OrderID", "Freight", "Freight1", "Freight2" };
    foreach (string uniqueName in numericColumns)
    {
        int index = -1;
        decimal maxNumber = decimal.MinValue;
        foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            decimal currentNumber = decimal.Parse(dataItem[uniqueName].Text);
            if (currentNumber > maxNumber)
            {
                maxNumber = currentNumber;
                index = dataItem.ItemIndex;
            }
        }
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            GridTableCell cell = (RadGrid1.Items[index] as GridDataItem)[uniqueName] as GridTableCell;
            cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.